# Angular JS: Pass a form's select option value as parameter on ng-submit="doStuff()"

Tags: angularjs

I've simplified my code down to this:

```
<form ng-submit="doStuff($('select').val())">
  <select name="menu">
    <option value="foo">bar</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I want angular to pass `<select>`'s value is to the function `doStuff()`. Whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You dont need to pass the dropdown's value to the submit handler.

It would be available as **$scope.menu** inside the doStuff method.

Also, you should use angular's **ng-options** to fill the options inside the dropdown:

```
<form ng-submit="doStuff()">
<select ng-model="menu" ng-options="item.name for item in items">       
</select>
```

Comment: Cool, I've been using `ng-repeat` to fill the options is it just as suitable as `ng-options`?

Comment: You should not use ng-repeat to fill the dropdown options. Angular has specifically provided ng-options for this purpose.