# AngularJS: Shows reference error : goToFormDashboard not defined in scope

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to call a function on onchange event but getting reference error everytime for that function my fromtend code is this:

```
        <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-controller="manageTeam">
            <div class="input-label">
                Select Form
            </div>
            <select onchange="goToFormDashboard($(this).children(':selected').val())" ng-model="Formname" ng-options="f.Formname for f in forms track by f.Formid"></select>
        </label>
```

My controller is this:

```
.controller('manageTeam', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $http, $timeout, $rootScope, $state) {
    $scope.goToFormDashboard = function (formId) {
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading'});
        $timeout(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, 1500);
        var formID = formId;
        $scope.form.length = 0;
        .....
```

is something missing in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ng-change` directive & no need to use jquery here you can get the value inside `ng-model`, `Formname` contains whole object you can pass form id only by doing `Formname.Formid` to `goToFormDashboard` method.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-change="goToFormDashboard(Formname.Formid)" ng-model="Formname" 
ng-options="f.Formname for f in forms track by f.Formid"></select>
```

Comment: i am using webstorm IDE with ionic framework, in the dropdown suggestion ng-change is not there & probably is not working too

Comment: if IDE intellesense dont showing that doesn't mean is `ng-change` will not work, `ng-change`  must work with angular..

Comment: i tried ng-change even if it was not showing on dashboard, it is not working & i am not getting the error too but not even getting the event happeped that i wrote in the controller...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript "this" means the function, from which the actual method was called. Example:

```
var myObject = function();
myObject.prototype.testvar = "hello world";
myObject.prototype.test = function(){ 
  return this.testvar;
}
var obj = new myObject();
console.log(obj.test());
```

this would display "hello world" in your chrome console. You dont need to pass the dropdown's value to the submit handler. just have a look at

[Angular JS: Pass a form's select option value as parameter on ng-submit="doStuff()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987682/angular-js-pass-a-forms-select-option-value-as-parameter-on-ng-submit-dostuff)

this is exactly what you are searching for

Comment: i am not getting ng-submit in dropdown suggestion in my IDE rather am getting data-ng-submit...